# C# struggling with sockets and trying to controll a hardware device op tcp/ip

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm new to c# and try to control a device over tcp/ip. The device behaves as the server so what i have done so far is that my client program initiates the connection and successfully connects to the device.
But that's all i have. Once the connection is established the device starts sending all these hex strings that i somehow need to parse. I have the protocol manual for the device so i know how to read them but i have absolutely no idea how i would implement this in c#.
What i think that needs to be done is that i constantly need to listen for the device to send data.
Then i somehow need to find complete hex command strings. I know every string starts with "0x10, 0x02" and ends with the hex chars "0x10, 0x03".
The device dictates that i also need to send some sort of acknowledge message every time i receive a string. "0x10, 0x06" (ack) So there has to be some sort of two way communication.
Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: do you know how to read data into a byte array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MongZhu please explain.

Comment: I don't know exactly how your code looks like. Do you have a `TcpListener` object that accepts a client and gets the Stream? can you post this connection code? do you know this [Read method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=DE-DE&k=k(System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got to keep the incoming data in a buffer and keep looking for that end character. When you find both start and end characters, you can run your custom "parse" method to extract the information and clear the buffer.

Here's a good starting point:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

In the server part you can find an example of looking for the end character:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example